# Couldn't evaluate the test script: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, postman, response

I'm new to Javascript and JSON and wondering if anyone could help with this error. My GET API returns the JSON file below (it returns 35749 items so for simplicity I just showed 2 of them here)

```
{
    "searchTotalMatch": 35749,
    "searchItems": [
        {
            "accountId": 1,
            "accountNumber": "32520A22DF0X",
            "accountName": "3M Company",
        },
        {
            "accountId": 2,
            "accountNumber": "43371C22DF0X",
            "accountName": "Risk Managed Insurance Consortiu",
        }
        ]
}
```

I want to find the accountName of the account that thas accountId as 100 and save it to a collection variable(TESTACCOUNT), and I wrote the test script below:

```
var responseData = pm.response.json().searchItems;
var test_account = responseData.find((item) => item.accountId === "100");
pm.collectionVariables.set('TESTACCOUNT', test_account.accountNumber);
```

I got the error message of
Couldn't evaluate the test script:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accountNumber')

Does this mean it didn't filter out the item at all? What is wrong with the script? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `item.accountId === "100"`. From the object, you're **strictly** comparing an integer with a `string`. Either do `item.accountId == "100"` (two equals) or `item.accountId === 100`. Hence, `test_account` is undefined.

Comment: `"100"` is a string, but the actual data uses numbers (`2`).

Comment: You don't actually have any tests in that script.  You should probably test that the test_account variable isn't undefined before setting the collection variable.  Also console log is your friend.  Console log the output of the find to check that it is working properly while debugging.  Which it won't be because of the reasons outlined by the previous commentators.  String vs Integer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are converting your api response into json using below code -

```
var responseData = pm.response.json().searchItems;
```

Please note that json() method is asynchronous and you would need to either use `await` or `then()` to get the final value.

So, you can add `await` in above mentioned code and make the following changes -

```
var responseData = await pm.response.json(); // don't forget to add async to the wrapper method
var searchItems = responseData.searchItems;
```

Also, replace "100" with 100 in below code -

```
var test_account = responseData.find((item) => item.accountId === "100");
```

Comment: I don't think the postman api has asynchronous response.json() according to the docs. This is not the fetch api. https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-with-response-data

Answer (score 0):

**You could do the following:**

- Change 100 to "100" (Use number instead of string)
- Change strict equals to equals ( == instead of ===)

You can also avoid errors, by using a conditional membership operator

test_account **?.** accountNumber **instead of** test_account **.** accountNumber

But note that, this will store undefined if your test_account is undefined, it avoids the error by looking for the member accountNumber if and only if test_account exists.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).